# From one point to another

Tags: prolog

With the following facts,

```
 x(p1,d1,c,d,e,f),
 y(d1,d2,i,j,k,l),
 z(d2,d3,o,p,q,r),
```

Thinking in them as points, I want to move from `x` to `z` doing the `p1` and `d3` input.

Having:

```
 write('Partida: '),nl, 
 read(Partida_it),
 write('Destino: '),nl, 
 read(Destino_it),
 viagem(Partida_it,Destino_it,C,D,E,F),nl,
 write(Partida_it),write('<-->'),write(Destino_it),nl,
 write('Tipo: '),write(C),nl,
 write('Hora de partida: '),write(D),nl,
 write('Hora de chegada: '),write(E),nl,
 write('Preco: '),write(F),nl,
 fail,
```

In case that connection already exists^

```
viagem(Partida_it,B,C,D,_,P1),nl,
viagem(B,Destino_it,F,_,E,P2),nl,
P is P1+P2,
write(Partida_it),write('<-->'),write(Destino_it),nl,
write('Tipo: '),write(C),write('e'),write(F),nl,
write('Hora de partida: '),write(D),nl,
write('Hora de chegada: '),write(E),nl,
write('Preco: '),write(P),nl,
fail.
```

Im stuck here while now, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand how can I think of `x(p1,d1,c,d,e,f)` as a point. It's a bunch of letters. Some of them with numbers. Spanish naming in the code is not making it more understandable as well.

Comment: I didnt express myself as I intended, they are, basicly, trips from one city to another, and all the information about them, for instance:
viagem(start,destiny,type_of_transportation,start_time,arrival_time,price).

Comment: the most important thing - imho - separate the computation from printing. Prolog is done to explore alternatives, then printing 'results' could be disappointing and pointless